# AWS server routing with route 53 geolocation based on user choice of location

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, geolocation, amazon-route53

Here's a scenario:

I have users accessing the website from across the world. Due to the data protection policies, certain data needs to reside at the servers in that country itself. This can be made possible using route 53 geolocation. But, I have a user who constantly travels between two countries and has a login from one country and tries to access data sitting in another country (on a business trip). Now, how can I let him access that particular data from a server present in country number one using route 53?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you saying that that you have services in multiple AWS regions (or is Route 53 pointing at your own data centers)? And do your services in each region store their own copy of data, such that each region operates independently? (Is this an actual situation you find yourself in, or is this a sample exam question you found somewhere?)

Comment: Is this actually a real policy ? You mentioned users accessing the website from across the world, I have read policy where companies mostly EU where they want to keep servers within their country which is quite possible.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, this is an actually scenario for one of my clients. They currently have multiple domain such as ca.example.com, au.example.com. But, they want a single page www.example.com that provides the user with info.

Comment: @JamesDean, the scenario might be such that, the user might be a resident of EU, his data is stored at servers in EU, now if he tries to login and access his data from the same www.example.com portal, we need to be able to fetch his information from the EU server and display to him...

Comment: @ArjunKashyap have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/) and got to sub section DNS Routing Policies on left hand side and search for this question "Can I have a Geo DNS record for a continent and different Geo DNS records for countries within that continent? Or a Geo DNS record for a country and Geo DNS records for states within that country?", the answer of this question might help you.

Also you can try to create IAM role for that User so that he can access the data using the IAM credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site is `www.example.com` and that hostname uses geolocation routing... and assuming you have systems in the US and the EU, you'll need additional hostnames in DNS that *do not* use georouting, e.g. `eu.example.com` pointing directly to the EU cluster, and give your user that URL -- or redirect the user to that URL.

There isn't a way to bypass georouting for a specific user on the "www" site, because the user has already been connected to one location according to your routing policy before the individual user has been identified.